# Core Data with sqlite returning only 3 rows

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

My database has two tables *ZDESTINATION* and *ZPOSTIT*.  There is many to one relationship, one `PostIt` can have many `Destination`s.  I want to get all the `Destination` rows (there are 9 of them) and I am using `NSFetchRequest`.  But only 3 rows are being returned.  I have not specified a predicate. I have a sort order and a section keynamepath as `@"postIt.creationTime"`.  I checked the database and all `postIts` have a creation time and all destinations have a valid `postit` relation.

This is the very simplified query.

```
SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.ZPOSTIT
FROM ZDESTINATION t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN ZPOSTIT t1 ON t0.ZPOSTIT = t1.Z_PK
WHERE t0.Z_PK IN (?,?,?)
ORDER BY t1.ZCREATIONTIME DESC
LIMIT 20
```

DESTINATION (Primary key, PostIt)

```
"1" "3"
"2" "2"
"3" "4"
"4" "5"
"5" "5"
"6" "5"
"7" "7"
"8" "7"
"9" "7"
```

POSTIT primary key, creation time

```
"1" "442134908.015139"
"2" "442134921.469915"
"3" "442134941.083225"
"4" "442135028.839804"
"5" "442212344.121323"
"6" "442212468.053344"
"7" "442214203.670005"
```

Note the LEFT OUTERJOIN is generated automatically by the fetch request.

Would you have any ideas or tips on how this might be debugged?

This is the Core Data `NSFetchRequest`.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [ [ NSFetchRequest alloc ] init ];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [ NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Destination"
                                           inManagedObjectContext:studyStageAssets.postItMoContext ];
[ fetchRequest setEntity:entity ];

// Create the sort descriptors array.
NSSortDescriptor *creationTimeDescriptor = [ [ NSSortDescriptor alloc ]
                                            initWithKey:@"postIt.creationTime"
                                            ascending:NO ];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[ creationTimeDescriptor ];
[ fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors ];

// Create and initialize the fetch results controller.
_fetchedResultsController = [ [ NSFetchedResultsController alloc ]
                             initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                             managedObjectContext:studyStageAssets.postItMoContext
                             sectionNameKeyPath:@"postIt.creationTime"
                             cacheName:@"TrailIt" ];

_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

This is immediately followed by `performFetch`.

Comment: Where does the WHERE clause come from?

Comment: Could you provide the fetch request?

Comment: Add the Core Data code you're using, because this is not a useful description of what you have actually tried.

Comment: I have added in the code for the fetch request.  @CL - The WHERE Clause is generated internally and I used -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1 on the arguments passed at launch for Core Data to emit debug statements. I have not put a predicate so the WHERE clause is generated automatically by Core Data.

Comment: I now downloaded the recipes sample app, and if I generate a similar query on ingredients, there is no WHERE clause being generated there.  So something in my code or schema is causing the WHERE clause.

Comment: This seems to me to be a bug in CoreData.  If I copy my database exactly as it to the Recipes app it works flawlessly. So, I found a workaround, where I do a dummy NSFetchRequest call right after creating the model at init.  Identical NSFetchRequest but I throw away the results. There is now no WHERE clause - neither for the first dummy call nor for the second real call.  So it seems that the Core Data is using some predicate left around if I don't assign a predicate to the NSFetchRequest.  I should probably report it in as bug, unless you have other suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the NSFetchedResultsController's cache?

Comment: Awesome.  That worked and I got rid of the dummy call as well.  [ NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"CacheName" ]; just before the performFetch did it for me.  If you want to put that in as answer I can accept it.  Thanks @flexaddicted for both editing my question to be clearer and everyone for your help on this.

Comment: @nishant Added as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, the problem is probably due to the fetched results controller's cache.  You can clear it with

```
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"TrailIt"];
```